# After jQuery div empty not possible to add data again in the div box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

On double click add data in the right side div box there is 2 option to delete box data, one option deletes a single row and other option empty full div. only box full empty function only work. If full box empties not possible to add data again.

**check image**

[image]

```js
<script>
  
function saveGLDObjective(el, data) {
return $('#' + el).find('.card-body').find('.card-block').append(
    '<div class="row border-bottom cartlo appGLDOutcomeId"  data-gldid="' + data.id + '">' +
    '<div class="col-lg-11 pl-0">' +
    '<p>' + data.content + '</p>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="col-lg-1 pr-0 text-right"><i class="fa fa-times-circle text-danger mt-2" title="Close" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>' +
    '</div>',
);
  }

  function saveLearningObjective(el, data) {
return $('#' + el).find('.card-body').find('.card-block').append(
    '<div class="row border-bottom cartlo appLearningOutcomeId"  data-id="' + data.id + '">' +
    '<div class="col-lg-11 pl-0">' +
    '<p>' + data.content + '</p>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="col-lg-1 pr-0 text-right"><i class="fa fa-times-circle text-danger mt-2" title="Close" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>' +
    '</div>',
);
  }

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<div class="card sidecard mt5">
                    <div class="card-header1">
                    Content Objective(s) / Learning Outcome(s)
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body p-2 innercard scro" id="div1">
                        <div id="empty">
                            <div id="showlo">
                                <div id="accordionWrap122" class="accordion"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body p-2 text-center">
                        <button class="btn btn-info mb-0 p-1" id="emptybox">Empty My Selections</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

```
   $("#emptybox").click(function() {
            $("#empty").empty();
        });
        $("#emptyboxskill").click(function() {
            $("#emptyskill").empty();
        });




  $('.fa-times-circle').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent('.cartlo').remove();
  });  





</script>


                <div class="card sidecard mt5">
                    <div class="card-header1">
                    Content Objective(s) / Learning Outcome(s)
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body p-2 innercard scro" id="div1">
                        <div id="empty">
                            <div id="showlo">
                                <div id="accordionWrap122" class="accordion"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body p-2 text-center">
                        <button class="btn btn-info mb-0 p-1" id="emptybox">Empty My Selections</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: (offtopic) `fa-times-circle` is a fontawesone class to paint *times* icon - it should not be used in your JS business logic as a selector that triggers events of any kind.

Comment: Well let me give you just a simple point, it might work for you, I don't know what are you trying to achieve you have so congested code. But you can use it like this `$(document).on('click','#emptybox',function() { //Your code logic });` also for second one `$(document).on('click','#emptyboxskill',function() { //Your code logic });` and also for 3rd one `$(document).on('click','.fa-times-circle',function() { //Your code logic });`